# Is there a way to test Azure pipeline changes on top of stages that have already run?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is there a way to test pipeline changes on a stage that has finished running? It would be super useful when a stage has failed and instead of running the entire pipeline to test your changes, you could trigger a rerun of the stage with the updated yml file.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, re-running a stage means running it the same way as it was run initially. When you think about, this is the very desired behaviour.

For pipeline development purposes, I would recommend cloning the pipeline and removing all unnecessary steps. Then work in this minimal/debugging pipeline for faster feedback.